# Baby Rudin Theorem 2.30 Counter Example?

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem 2.30: Suppose $Y\subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and
only if $E = Y\cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

So, suppose we are considering subsets of the real line $X=R$.  Let $Y = [1,2]$ and $G = (0,3)$.  Then $E = Y\cap G = [1,2]$ which is not open.  So, it seems like $Y$ has to be open.  Is this Correct?

Perhaps, it really has to do with the definition of $E$ as being open relative to $Y$: to each $p\in E$ there is associated an $r > 0$ such that $q\in E$ whenever $d(p, q) < r$ ***and*** $q\in Y$.  Hence, in the counter example above, we do not consider any $q\not\in[1,2]$.  This does not seem to be a very stringent definition of openness.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help explain this!

-Jason

Comment: A set is neither intrinsically closed nor open. A set is only open or closed relative to some topology. When we talk about a set being open or closed relative to some subset of a metric space, we are changing our topology from the metric topology on the whole space to the subspace topology.

Answer (score 1):

Well... here is the way I see it now.  Let's say that $E$ is open with respect to $Y$ if for each $p\in E$ there exists a neighborhood $N_{r_p}(p)\subset X$ such that $N_{rp}(p)\cap Y\subset E$ then it seems obvious that my example is not counter.

Let $p$ be any point in $[1,2] = Y\cap G$, and $N_{r_p}(p)$ be any neighborhood containing $p$; then $N_{r_p}(p)\cap Y = N_{r_p}(p)\cap [1,2]\subset E = [1,2]$ so that $E$ is open with respect to $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$(X, \tau) $ be any topological space and $Y\subset X$.

Then $\tau_Y=\{G\cap Y : U\in \tau \}$ is a topology on $Y$( in fact smallest topology on $Y$ for which the inclusion map $\iota:Y\to X$ is continuous).

$(Y, \tau_Y) $ is called topological subspace of $(X, \tau) $.

$E\subset Y$ is open in $Y$ i.e $E\in \tau_Y$ iff $E=Y\cap G$ for some $G\in \tau$

---

For $X=\Bbb{R}$ , $Y=[1, 2]$ and $G=(0, 3) $ , $E=Y\cap G=[1, 2]$.

Then $[1, 2]$ is open in $[1, 2]$ i.e $[1, 2]\in \tau_Y$ ( be careful it doesn't say that $[1, 2]$ is open in $(X, \tau) $)

$E$ here seems trivial as underlying set in it's topology is always open.

Let's try to show $E= [1, \frac{3}{2}) $ is open in $([1,2], \tau_{[1,2]}) $

Comment: Hi Lost in Space, thanks so much for your reply.  Your nomenclature is a little new for me:  "$(Y,\tau_Y)$ seems clear, but I am little unsure about $U$.  However, it seems that the point is that (here I am substituting my own nomenclature) $(G\cap Y, \tau_Y)$ is a metric space in its own right.  Nevertheless, I believe my confusion originated from the definition of "open w/ respect to".  Would it be equivalent to state that $E$ is open with respect to $Y$ if for each $p\in E$ there exists a neighborhood $N_{r_p}(p)$ such that $N_{r_p}(p)\cap Y\subset E$?

Comment: True. As open balls form a base. $E\subset Y$ open in $Y$ implies $\forall p\in E, \exists N_{r_p}$ such that $N_{r_p}\cap Y\subset E$